# Vector projection in 2d application

Tags: calculus

Can somebody please give me an easy application of vector projection in 2D. I dont want to see an example in physics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The shadow of a thin object in the plane of the object and the light source.

Component of load force along one member in a joint of two straight beams.  (Engineering.)

Comment: I know this, but I am thinking of an application in real world.

Comment: Light and shadows aren't the real world?  Okay, I'll add another one.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not specific to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but [least squares approximation](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~ifischer/Intro_Stat/Lecture_Notes/APPENDIX/A2._Geometric_Viewpoint/A2.3_-_Least_Squares_Approximation.pdf) is a very well-known application of orthogonal projection to very "real world" purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Think about simple linear regression (OLS) in statistics.  In this case, we want to model data $y$ in terms of $x$, such that $$y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon.$$

If $y$ is your $n \times 1$ vector of data, then you are projecting it onto two vectors:

1. An $n \times 1$ vector of one's.
2. An $n \times 1$ vector of the independent variable $x$.

Bringing these two vectors together as columns of a $n \times 2$ matrix $X$, we can then write the OLS esitmate of $(\alpha, \beta)$ as a parameter vector $\hat{\beta} = (XX')^{-1}X'y$, such that $$E[y] = X\hat{\beta},$$ and the projection matrix is $P = X(XX')^{-1}X',$ thus the expectation is really $$E[y] = Py,$$ or the projection of $y$ onto $x$ and a scalar dimension.